# Combine 2 tables in SQL including uncommon fields

Tags: sql

I have two tables as follows:

```
    table 1                           table 2
id   name   count1      |         id   name   count2
1     x       2                   1     x       1
2     y       3                   4     y       1
3     z       1                   5     z       2
```

Result expected:

```
id   name   count1  count2
1     x       2        1         
2     y       3        0          
3     z       1        0
4     y       0        1
5     z       0        2
```

SQL query tried:

```
SELECT table1.id as id, table1.name as name, 
table1.count1 as count1, table2.count2 as count2
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 on table1.id = table2.id and table1.name = table2.name
```

I feel like this is wrong because I am not getting the expected result. I am unsure of which join to use since I am new. Any help here would be much appreciated.

Thank you very much

Comment: Just a note, tables have _columns_, not fields. (A _field_ in SQL is something else, either a part of a date/time value, or a part of a record data type.)

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: "I am not getting the expected result" - and what result is that? and why is it wrong/unexpected?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `UNION ALL` within the subquery and then aggregate in the main query as

```
SELECT id, name, SUM(count1) AS count1, SUM(count2) AS count2
  FROM
 (
  SELECT id, name, count1, 0 AS count2 
    FROM table1
   UNION ALL
  SELECT id, name, 0, count2  
    FROM table2
 ) q
GROUP BY id, name
```

Comment: NB that `UNION ALL`. It is important NOT to use `UNION` here since `UNION` will remove duplicate from the subquery which is not what you want!

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan They just meant that readers should be careful to retain the `ALL`, i.e. that it is non-default and meaningful.

Comment: I know @underscore_d , but nothing gotta do with this answer :)

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan you're answer is fine! I upvoted it. My message about the `ALL` was to the OP & other readers to be sure to not leave it out. What @underscore_d said :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `full join`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.id, t2.id) as id, COALESCE(t1.name, t2.name) as name,
       COALESCE(t1.count1, 0) as count1, COALESCE(t2.count2, 0) as count2
table1.count1 as count1, table2.count2 as count2
FROM table1 t1 FULL JOIN
     table2 t2 
     ON t1.id = t2.id and t1.name = t2.name;
```

If your database does not support `full join`, then you basically have two options.  One only uses `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT ni.id, ni.name,
       COALESCE(t1.count1, 0) as count1, COALESCE(t2.count2, 0) as count2
table1.count1 as count1, table2.count2 as count2
FROM ((SELECT id, name FROM table1
      ) UNION  -- on purpose to remove duplicates
      (SELECT id, name FROM table2
      )
     ) ni LEFT JOIN
     table1 t1
     ON t1.id = ni.id AND ni.name = t1.name
     table2 t2 
     ON ni.id = t2.id and ni.name = t2.name;
```

The second method is uses `UNION ALL`, NOT `UNION`:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t1.count1, COALESCE(t2.count2, 0) as count2
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
     table2 t2 
     ON t1.id = t2.id and t1.name = t2.name
UNION ALL
SELECT t2.id, t2.name, 0, t2.count2
FROM table2 t2 LEFT JOIN
     table1 t1
     ON t1.id = t2.id and t1.name = t2.name
WHERE t1.id IS NULL;
```

I have no idea where the "canonical" approach using `UNION` comes from.  I think it is a thought exercise on being close.  However, it is a very poor solution for the following reasons:

- `UNION` adds additional overhead for removing duplicates.  And that is not part of `FULL JOIN` functionality.
- The lack of `WHERE` clause on the second query ensures that there are duplicates if there are any matches.
- The use of `UNION` removes duplicates *within* each subquery.  Whether desirable or not, that is not how `FULL JOIN` works.